# If gemfire.properties is specified then Geode locator fails to start

Tags: geode

I am working through the [SSL example](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/managing/security/ssl_example.html) which means starting the locator using the properties files instead of default. So it's

`start locator --name=IsLocator --properties-file=..\config\gemfire.properties --security-properties-file=..\config\gfsecurity.properties`

Then whether the SSL is set in the properties files or not, this causes the locator process to terminate with an error

```
The Locator process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 1. Please refer to the log file in D:\Geode\bin\IsLocator for full details.

Sep 21, 2017 11:23:22 AM org.apache.geode.distributed.LocatorLauncher failOnStart
INFO: locator is exiting due to an exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write to deploy directory: D:\tmp
at org.apache.geode.internal.JarDeployer.loadPreviouslyDeployedJarsFromDisk(JarDeployer.java:410)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.initialize(GemFireCacheImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.basicCreate(GemFireCacheImpl.java:758)
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.create(GemFireCacheImpl.java:745)
at org.apache.geode.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:173)
at org.apache.geode.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:212)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalLocator.startCache(InternalLocator.java:723)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalLocator.startDistributedSystem(InternalLocator.java:710)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalLocator.startLocator(InternalLocator.java:324)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.LocatorLauncher.start(LocatorLauncher.java:651)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.LocatorLauncher.run(LocatorLauncher.java:553)
at org.apache.geode.distributed.LocatorLauncher.main(LocatorLauncher.java:195)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to write to deploy directory: D:\tmp
at org.apache.geode.internal.JarDeployer.verifyWritableDeployDirectory(JarDeployer.java:333)
at org.apache.geode.internal.JarDeployer.loadPreviouslyDeployedJarsFromDisk(JarDeployer.java:389)
... 11 more`
```

The same error happens if GFSH is started as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

This problem resolves if you remove the `deploy-working-dir` property.